# JQM Navigation bug using $.mobile.navigate()

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, navigation, phonegap-build

I have been searching for a solution for this problem for more than two days

I am using $.mobile.navigate() to navigate between pages, but after going  back and forward (PAGE_A > PAGE_B || PAGE_B > PAGE_A) more than 4 time, for some estrange reason it take me back to PAGE_B

this example explain the issue:

Comment: UPDATE: This this link to view example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g5vAN/88/)

Comment: use `pageinit` to bind/attach events as it fires once. `pagebeforeshow` fires continuously which duplicates listeners. Also, use `$.mobile.changePage()` not `.navigate()`. http://jsfiddle.net/g5vAN/90/